# Customize the background of horizontal progress bar

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I got a horizontal progress bar and I wanted to change the background. I wanted to divide the background into 4 parts as shown below(just that the shape of my progress bar is rectangular). I found that there are lots of examples showing the way of changing the background color of the progress bar, but I got no idea how to divide the background. Any idea for this?

[image: The shape of my progress bar is rectangular]

Comment: it is impossible to do it using any xml files,  you need to extend Drawable class to get it working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify the background, primary progress, and secondary progress separately in your progress bar background XML using layer IDs. Here is how the default Holo progress bar is set up:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background"
          android:drawable="@drawable/progress_bg_holo_light" />

    <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
        <scale android:scaleWidth="100%"
               android:drawable="@drawable/progress_secondary_holo_light" />
    </item>

    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <scale android:scaleWidth="100%"
               android:drawable="@drawable/progress_primary_holo_light" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

You'll probably want to use `<clip>` instead of `<scale>`, but you get the idea.

Comment: Means that I need to draw the background by my own?Then what should be the size of the image?

Comment: Use the images you already posted as PNG drawable resources. The gray one is your background layer, the fully-filled colored one is your progress layer. You can remove the secondary progress item.